# Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have created a newsletter plugin. I have coded an export function, but I got this error:

> Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at **C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\wp-includes\script-loader.php:1005**) in **C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\wp-content\plugins\newsletter\export.php** on line **4**.

I tried many ways, but in vain. Please suggest me the best way to solve this issue.

Comment: make debug mode false and run

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: made debug mode false but no result